# Browsers displayed incorrect way in Browser Link Dashboard

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to debug ASP.NET core MVC (.Net 6) application with many browsers (Google, Edge) in Visual Studio 2022 Community.
[image]

They opening and working as expected, but displayed incorrectly in Browser Link Dashboard

[image]

What should I do to see Browser Title in dashboard?

I have already set "Enable Browser Link" and uncheck "Stop debugger when browser window is closed"